Rails activerecord-import not work with unique key
model
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end


schema
create_table 'users',
             force: :cascade,
             charset: 'utf8mb4',
             collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' do |t|
  t.string 'name'
  t.timestamps
  t.index %w[name], name: 'index_name_on_users'
end


problem code (import.rb)
names = ['a','b','c','d']
users = []
names.each do |name|
  users << User.new(
    name: name,
  )
end


User.import(
  users,
  on_duplicate_key_update: %i[name]
)

Running import.rb twice saves a,b,c,d twice despite user is having a unique key (8 users saved with name: a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d)
Is there a way to save user records with unique key enabled?
(I'm not considering User.find_by & skipping because of performance..)

You have not recreated a unique key constraint on name in the database -- also if it is a postgres db you need to be more explicit with the on_duplicate_key_update -- https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import?tab=readme-ov-file#duplicate-key-update

Your model level validation will not occur based on your usage. If you look at the available Options you can see it validates by default but specifies that uniqueness validations will be skipped. to enable them you have to pass validate_uniqueness: true as an option. Alternatively if a database error is acceptable then you can add unique: true to your index creation.
